# Rail custom delayed job queue with variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

In my project I have some Delayed Jobs that take a while to process.
While few people uses server, that's not a problem to run all of them in one queue (other Jobs run in another queue, surely). But I'm afraid about this if number of users rise. Every job will execute longer and longer because of waiting.

So I thought what if I create queues with variable names?
Smth like

```
def queue_name
  "queue_#{Time.now}"
end
```

---

All below is actual only in case previous solution is making sense.
Ok, if it could be done using Time. But what about I want to put job into queue with user id in name? I mean one queue per user.

```
def queue_name(user_id) #what id it could be passed here somehow?..
  "user_#{user_id}"
end
```

Thanx!

Comment: Putting jobs in differently named queues will reduce the waiting time only if there are separate Workers for each queue. And you can achieve the same results by using one queue and having multiple workers picking jobs from this queue.

Comment: @Reub oh.. someone like me should read docs more careful:) And what's the matter giving different names for queues then? Just to make it prettier? (I can imagine complicated configuration when there are a lot of workers grabbing from different queue combinations, but it doesn't seem real for me)

Comment: Queues also help to organise delayed jobs into groups. For example, if you've got a large number of jobs and you need to find a job created from a particular class. If every delayed job class has a different queue_name, it becomes easy to search, you can now search only within a particular queue by using `Delayed::Job.where(queue: 'some_queue_name')`

Comment: @Reub Now I see. Thank you a lot!